# How to get a list of open Excel workbooks in PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell

When I use PowerShell, I only get one (Workbook3) of several window titles (Workbook1, Workbook2, Workbook3), but I want to get the entire list of all open Excel books. I am trying to use the following code:

```
[array]$Titles = Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.mainWindowTItle} |Foreach-Object {$_.mainwindowtitle}

ForEach ($item in $Titles){Write-Host $item}
```

[image]

UPD. (We get a list of books, but we don't see which ones only to read)
If I open the book in read-only mode, it will not be visible in the output of the program. In the Task Manager this mark is in the name of the window.

```
$excel = [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::
          GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')

ForEach ( $wkb in $excel.workbooks ) {
  $wkb.Name
}
```

[image]

Comment: That's odd. Seems like Microsoft went on to only show one instance  of it running: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10-mso_2016/what-are-excel-instances-and-why-is-this-important/20c39a6f-0857-4033-b713-18bf72e91d8b. Now im curious too, as the win32_process class gave me the same results. Maybe loading the com object, then checking is the (not best but, only) solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, my solution:

```
Clear-Host
Remove-Variable * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$excel = [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')
$date = Get-Date -Format "d.MM.y HH:mm"
$person = $env:UserName

#arrays with books and status
ForEach ( $book in $excel.workbooks ) {$books_names = ,$book.Name + $books_names}
ForEach ( $book in $excel.workbooks ) {$books_reads = ,$book.ReadOnly + $books_reads}

#print
#ForEach ($item in $books_names){$item}
#ForEach ($item in $books_reads){$item}

#delete empty string
$books_names = $books_names[0..($books_names.Count-2)]
$books_reads = $books_reads[0..($books_reads.Count-2)]

#replace
$books_reads = $books_reads -replace "False" , "write."
$books_reads = $books_reads -replace "True" , "read"

# Table view
$t = $books_names |%{$i=0}{[PSCustomObject]@{person= $person; date= $date;book=$_; status=$books_reads[$i]};$i++}
#$t | ft
#$t | Out-GridView

# write to txt
Add-Content "C:\My\1.txt" $t | ft

#pause
```

1.txt looks like:

```
@{person=BelyaevKN; date=14.06.21 14:05; book=workbook1; status=write}
@{person=BelyaevKN; date=14.06.21 14:05; book=workbook2; status=read}
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems to do the trick:

```
Clear-Host

$excel = [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::
          GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')

ForEach ( $wkb in $excel.workbooks ) {
  $wkb.Name
}
```

Sample Output:

```
PERSONAL.xlsm
Cash Count.xls
Check Calc.xls
Coke Price Comparison Sheet.xls
PS>
```

HTH

Comment: But if I open the book in read-only mode, it will not be visible in the output of the program. In the Task Manager this mark is in the name of the window